# Changing color of specific Row in Telerik UWP RadDataGrid

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, telerik, telerik-grid

I have the following XAML in my view:

```
<tg:RadDataGrid ColumnDataOperationsMode="Flyout"  x:Name="grid3" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.MappingSource}" SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentMapping, Mode=TwoWay}" UserEditMode="{x:Bind ViewModel.CanEdit, Mode=TwoWay}"  Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowBackground="{x:Bind ViewModel.ValidateModBank}">
```

Please take a look at the end of the line where it sets the `RowBackground` property. At this time my `ValidateModBank` property returns the color red based on certain criteria.

The problem is that all the rows in the `RadDataGrid` get changed to red, but I only want specific rows to change - based on `ValidateModBank`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RowBackground` property is used to sets the Brush that defines the fill of each row, it's not for a specific row.

According to your description, you might want to change background of the selected row.

You could use its [Implicit Styling](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/raddatagrid/styling/datagrid-implicitstyling).

Setting the [SelectionRegionBackground Control](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/raddatagrid/styling/datagrid-implicitstyling#selectionregionbackground-control) for it.

```
<telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="gridPrimitives:SelectionRegionBackgroundControl">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    </Style>
</telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Resources>
```